# How I can activate 2th intellisense screen that show information of API about methods listed on intellisense screen on Eclipse?For Java

Tags: java

[image]I would like to know how to activate the second window of the intellisense pop-up menu in Eclipse where the API information of the method you have selected appears in the main window of the intillisense.

I have looked on the internet and most people when they talk about intellisense usually refer to the window that suggests the methods, but I did not see anyone talking about the second one.

Years ago this second screen worked by default in Eclipse, but from what I have seen in the latest version of Eclipse only the first window appears.
Does anyone know if it can be activated? How?

Thank you so much for your time and patience :)